# How to (cleanly?) solve equations across number sets?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

Consider the equation:
$$
\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{2}}=a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4} \quad a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}
$$
If $a,b,c$ were real, the equation would obviously have infinite solutions. But restricting them to the rationals leads to (supposedly) only one.

Using the identity

\begin{align}
x^3-y^3&=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)\quad x,y\in\mathbb{R}\\ 
\frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}&=x^2+xy+y^2
\end{align}
and choosing $x=1$ and $y=-\sqrt[3]{2}$, one can solve

\begin{align}
\frac{3}{1+\sqrt[3]{2}}&=1-\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}\\
\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{2}}&=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{2}+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{4}
\end{align}
it is then obvious that $a=\frac{1}{3}$, $b=-\frac{1}{3}$, $c=\frac{1}{3}$. The professor didn't explain further. My questions would be:

- Is there any clearer way to write this?
- Is there a universal method to solve this, other then "educated guessing" of $x$ and $y$?
- Is there any way to prove that this solution is indeed the only one?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know Linear Algebra?

Comment: If you've done some linear algebra. You can essentially think that, as $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{4}$ lie outside of $\mathbb{Q}$, they form in some sense a basis over $\mathbb{Q}$ and you are looking for linear combinations of these elements, such that the equation is satisfied. Many of the properties you are looking for, can then follow from that.

Comment: without guesswork, use the fact that over the rationals, $p + q\sqrt[3]{2} + r\sqrt[3]{2} = 0 $ iff $ p = q = r = 0$. So, if we cross multiply, then we want to solve for $1 = a + 2c, a+b = 0, b+c = 0$, which yields a unique solution which you found/guessed.

Comment: You can search and learn Extended Euclidean Algorithm, which is the general method to deal with this type of problems.